# How to update MySql column inline with existing rows without adding additional id's?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a MySql database with 170 entries already. The rows are auto incremented for the primary id. I added an additional column and want to fill that column with data that corresponds with the existing information. I already have the csv file with the data in the correct order. I am using GoDaddy. I tried importing the csv file but instead of adding the data inline with the existing data, it added the imported data to the end thus creating more id's which I didn't want to happen.

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry but I can't figure out how to add/show the csv/table here so this is the only way I could think of visually showing everyone whats going on and how it needs to be.

When I tried to import the csv for the last column it did this:
[Not how I wanted it](http://www.pspdemocenter.com/testing/wrong.htm)

I was trying to achieve this. The data in the last column is in the same row as the corresponding name in the first column:
[How I wanted it](http://www.pspdemocenter.com/testing/right.htm)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Do you have any way of matching values for a row, other than the ordering in the CSV files?

Comment: You can add a temp table with the CSV data and then update with join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know how to add the csv/table here so I did my best and created webpages of the differences with Excel provided in the links

Comment: @sagi I don't understand what you mean. Sorry.